# Why is Visual Studio Code showing a js error in my php file?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code setup for PHP and everything works fine. I was using the Intellisense plugin but moved to Intellephense instead because the former was too slow.

When I did that I started getting a 'js' error in my php file. The error in question is not really an error, the parser thinks it is because it does not recognize the  tags interspersed throughout the code. The file is a .php file so I don't know why vscode is even trying to lint it as javascript. The error in question is

> ',' expected.

The code is something like this and it does not like the comma after the `<?php` tag:

```
<?php 
            if ( ( something being test ) { ?>
            ,
```

What I want to know is, how do I just get it to stop linting my php code as javascript. I just want to make it stop telling me about the error and I am not familiar enough with vscode to know how to tell it to stop validating as js.

Comment: do you really have two opening parens on your `if`?  why dont you s how your real code ??

Comment: Sorry, no. I removed sensitive code and accidentally left an extra paren. What is in the if block is not important because the parser is ignoring it. It is complaining about an errant comma that is not a valid problem. What I really need to know is how to turn off the javascript syntax checking in VS Code.